# Eclipse + Github : Merge changes to forked repo

Tags: eclipse, git, github, merge

I have forked a repo on github, i create branches on the forked repo and commit changes - when im done im making a pull request to the original repo.

Now, if the original repo gets updates - how do i merge these changes into my forked repo (master branch) ? I found tutorials that explain how to do it with command line - but i like to use the integrated git tool in eclipse (mars).

I first checked out my own forked repo using eclipse, then i tried the Remote -> Configure Upstream option - and changed the repo not to my own but to the original one - then i simply fetched/pushed the changes; then i had to switch the remote upstream again to my forked repo - because eclipse somehow can now differentiate between a remote fetch and pull repo ?

Can somebody explain how i easily merge changes from an original repo to my forked one using eclipse ? I know i can use the github GUI to make a pull request to my own repo but i rather do it with eclipse

Comment: As a general rule of thumb - you will run into GUI-related issues with GIT all the time, so for your own sake I highly recommend to just accept that some things are better/easier/faster done via console. I know it's not easy.

Comment: I use console at work, however for the small things i do at home i dont need the full git env and why not use the git plugin eclipse offers ?